# Eslint issue - Too many additional files created

Tags: javascript, eslint

Hello to all pro Javascript coders.
I`ve started to use ESlint rescently. The problem that it creates node-folder with around 5000 files is this normal. Is it normal practice to keep these files in github repository with project?
Thank you for your responses!

Comment: in .gitignore file add /node_modules folder

Answer (score 0):

The normal thing is not to check anything build related into GitHub. This is done by creating a `.gitignore` file. GitHub will auto created this if you set the project type to `javascript` when you start a new project.

Or you can do it yourself by adding the following.

```
# Logs
logs
*.log
npm-debug.log*
yarn-debug.log*
yarn-error.log*

# Runtime data
pids
*.pid
*.seed
*.pid.lock

# Directory for instrumented libs generated by jscoverage/JSCover
lib-cov

# Coverage directory used by tools like istanbul
coverage

# nyc test coverage
.nyc_output

# Grunt intermediate storage (http://gruntjs.com/creating-plugins#storing-task-files)
.grunt

# Bower dependency directory (https://bower.io/)
bower_components

# node-waf configuration
.lock-wscript

# Compiled binary addons (https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html)
build/Release

# Dependency directories
node_modules/
jspm_packages/

# TypeScript v1 declaration files
typings/

# Optional npm cache directory
.npm

# Optional eslint cache
.eslintcache

# Optional REPL history
.node_repl_history

# Output of 'npm pack'
*.tgz

# Yarn Integrity file
.yarn-integrity

# dotenv environment variables file
.env

# next.js build output
.next

yarn.lock
```